# Page includes resources that are not secured - but where?

Tags: browser, ssl, https

Our HTTPS pages show a warning that some resources on the page are not secured.

I've been looking at Firebug, Fiddler, etc ... I can't understand which resources are not transmitted securely.

Is there a tool, browser or something that would help debugging this?

For reference, the page I'm looking at is https://www.makemeheal.com/mmh/login/login.do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
http://www.makemeheal.com/mmh/images/shared/silhouettes_ltblue.jpg
```

is being loaded from a non-SSL url. Firefox: Tools -> Page Info -> Media, scan for http:// intead of https://

Comment: Thanks. It fixed it in Firefox but not in Chrome. However I think I found out why: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=29465ba1a9c1cb7c&hl=en